# Counting special metrics on finite fields

Tags: co.combinatorics, finite-fields, coding-theory

Define a *Galois coding norm of degree n* as a map $|\space| : \Bbb F_{2^n}\rightarrow {\Bbb Z}$ with the following properties :

(I) **$(\Bbb F_{2^n},|\space|)$ is a self-orthogonal code** ; i.e. $(x,y)\rightarrow |x+y|$ defines a metric on $\Bbb F_{2^n}$ embedded via linear isometry as a self-orthogonal subcode of a universal code $\Bbb F_2^m$.

(II) **All field automorphisms are isometries**.

(III) For some normal basis **$\mathcal B_n$** of $\Bbb F_{2^n}$ and all $b\in \mathcal B_n$ left multiplication by $b$ defines an isometry.

1. Do I and II together imply III ? Do (I) and (III) together imply (II) ?
2. Must there exist a non-trivial galois coding norm of degree $n$ for each $n>1$ ? If so, how many satisfy $|1|=n$ ?

Infinitely many metrized finite fields arise as a subcode of a binary abelian group code on an odd group. In particular, when $p$ is prime and 2 generates the group squares in $\Bbb F_p^*$ then there is an ideal of the group ring $\Bbb F_2[\Bbb F_p^+]$ isomorphic to $\Bbb F_{2^{\frac {p-1}{2}}}$ whose inherited norm is galois with $|1|=\frac{p-1}{2}$.

Comment: I think that every generator of the cyclic group $\mathbf{F}_{2^n}^*$ is part of a normal basis and conversely each normal basis consists of elements generating $\mathbf{F}_{2^n}^*$, hence (III) is just equivalent to the requirement that the left multiplication by each $b\neq 0$ is a self-isometry. By transitivity, this forces $x\mapsto |x|$ to be constant on $\mathbf{F}_{2^n}$.

Comment: @YCor. (III) only states that there must exist at least 1 normal basis with said properties. Nothing in (III) says every normal basis has said properties. For example, the principle ideal $$C := <\sum_{t\in \Bbb R_{17}} t>$$ of the group ring $\Bbb F_2[\Bbb F_{17}^+]$ is ring isomorphic to the finite field $\Bbb F_{2^8}$ where $\Bbb R_{17}$ is the multiplicative group of squares in $\Bbb F_{17}$. $C$ is a group code whose norm satisfies (I) - (III) but non-constant.

Comment: (You commented twice the same, could you delete one instance?)

Comment: You're right, my mistake was the claim that each normal basis consists of elements (each) generating $\mathbf{F}_{2^n}^*$, and this is false for n=4, every element of order 5 in $\mathbf{F}_{16}^*$ is part of a normal basis.

Comment: In (I) you're asking to view $\mathbf{F}_{2^n}$ as self-dual subcode of $\mathbf{F}_2^n$... but these two have the same cardinal. Is it a typo, meaning "*as subcode of $\mathbf{F}_2^{2n}$* "?

Comment: @YCor. You're right. I changed "self-dual" to "self-orthogonal". Thanks.

Comment: Self-dual was fine. But don't you mean inside $F_2^{2n}$ and not $F_2^n$? Self-orthogonal implies half-dimensional.

Comment: @YCor. By self-orthogonal I mean that it is contained in its dual but not necessarily equal to its dual. By self-dual I mean it equals its dual. Interestingly, self-orthogonality is an intrinsic property because it just means that the usual bilinear form is degenerate on that space.

Comment: It means it's not only degenerate, but identically zero. I think "self-orthogonal" sounds misleading as it looks like it's equal to its orthogonal. I'd call it "purely isotropic", or plainly "contained in its orthogonal".

Comment: @YCor. Misleading perhaps but just the standard definition. As far as the degeneracy, I'm not sure but I think, with the other axioms and the field structure, degeneracy and pure isotropy are equivalent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99012/discussion-between-oliver-kayende-and-ycor).

Comment: Degenerate means having nonzero intersection to its orthogonal.

Comment: If even one non-trivial element x is degenerate, i.e. <x,y>= 0 for all y, then I think that with (II) and (III) this would mean that all elements are degenerate.

Comment: Proof : Imagine x is degenerate and non-trivial. The $\Bbb F_{2^n}$ subcode $H$ of degenerate codewords is mapped back onto itself by every linear isometry automorphism of $\Bbb F_{2^n}$. Given $y\in \Bbb F_{2^n}$ and with (II), (III) we must have $(b_1+b_2+...+b_j)*x \in H$ for any choice of $b_i\in\mathcal B_n$ implying $H$ is a $\Bbb F_{2^n}$ ideal and therefore $H=\Bbb F_{2^n}$

Comment: @YCor. Thank you.